# Regex - how to make my regex not pass when the string is blank

Tags: regex

I have a regex that will validate to make sure I have a number. but it passed if the string I'm checking is "" as well. how can I make a "" fail?

```
^(\\d|-)?(\\d|,)*\\.?\\d*$
```

Comment: Just check for "" separately. Boo regex, boo!

Comment: I want this to accept number:  1,120.03  or 100,100,200.30 or 10002 or .05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could require at least one digit:

```
^-?\d[\d,]*(?:\.\d+)?$
   ^^
required
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/rGwcCELay5)

To also allow matching .05:

```
^-?\d[\d,]*(?:\.\d+)?$|^-?\.\d+$
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/ck6ZrJihp9)

Note that your expression also allows multiple commas one after another which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?  There's undoubtedly a better way for you to detect "is this a number?" than rolling your own regex from scratch.  If you're using Perl, then look at the Regexp::Common module that provides dozens of time-tested regexes for your use.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
^-?([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

`^-?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$|^-?\.\d+$`

Tested it on Rubular, which is awesome (thanks, Mark!)  It'll accept some sloppy comma management, like "1234,567", but will reject obvious crap like "123,,,,456".

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper regex for *grouped* decimals:

```
^-?(?:\\.\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d*)?)$
```

- It accepts an initial sign.
- After that it creates a tree with two paths, either period or 1-3 digits.
- If it doesn't have either of those, it fails.
- If it sees a period, then it will take any number of digits, but at least 1.
- If it sees a digit cluster, it will take any number of groups consisting of comma + 3 digits.
- Then, you can have a decimal point, if you want and follow it up with as many digits as you would like.

The following fix handles ungrouped numbers as well:

```
^-?(?:\\.\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:\\d*|(?:,\\d{3})+)(\\.\\d*)?)$
```

But it does not allow somebody to include more than 3 in a group. Thus after 1-3 digits, there must be another digit or a comma or a period or the end.

- If it's a digit, then nothing but a digit or a period can follow.
- Given a comma, nothing but 3 digits can follow. We intensified this to 1 or more, since `\\d*` handles the case of an immediate period.